# Authenticating google calendar using authToken

Tags: android

How can I use an authToken string to manipulate a google calendar?  I understand how to get the authToken, but I don't understand how to use the authToken to access google calendar...

In the stackoverflow question below, the person says they append it to the url, but I just haven't been able to figure out where to put it...

[AuthToken from AccountManager in Android Client No Longer Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996686/authtoken-from-accountmanager-in-android-client-no-longer-working)

Can anyone please help me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've solved it now.  Once I created my calendar service...

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("UserCalendar");
```

I just needed to authenticate it using...

```
myService.setAuthSubToken(mytoken);
```